# Mapping values for nested array object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON API that responds with a data structure for a single record, with an array of associations nested in the record. An example of the api response looks like this:

```
{  
   "name":"foo",
   "bars":[  
      {  
         "name":"bar1"
      },
      {  
         "name":"bar2"
      },
      {  
         "name":"bar3"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to map the "bars" node to a react list of "paragraph" html tags, but I have had no success. I tried using "Object.keys.map" as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056399/how-to-iterate-nested-objects-and-render-inside-jsx) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61013/getting-multiple-keys-values-from-nested-object-in-json-w-out-jquery) but I still couldn't get the data transformation right.

I'm new to react/js so not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the <p> virtual DOM element
const { p } = React.DOM


// Your data mapped into the <p> element
// ps :: [ React.DOM ]
const ps = YourObj.bars.map((b, i) => p({key: i}, b.name))
//~> [ <p>bar1</p>, <p>bar2</p>, <p>bar3</p> ]
```

Now you can use `ps` wherever you please.

Answer (score 0):

`bars` in response is array - iterate it directly. Array provides `map` method to do so.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {response.bars.map((item, idx) => (
                <p key={idx}>{item.name}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Note: `response` is data received from API

Comment: You forgot to access the "name" property

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your JSON data is saved to an attribute named `record`.

```
const RecordItem = ({
  record
}) => (
  <div>
    {record.bars.map((bar, index) => (
      <p key={index}>{bar.name}</p>
    )}
  </div>
)

// Then, put this wherever:
<RecordItem record={record} />
```

Should do the trick! Obviously, modify to suit your needs.